# Incompatible JavaHL library for Subclipse in 64 bit Kubuntu

Tags: eclipse, javahl

I'm trying to get Subversion working under Eclipse 3.7 in a 64 bit Kubuntu 11.10 but having problems.  I've installed subclipse 1.8.1, installed 'libsvn-java' and have added `-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni/` under the `-vmargs` in the `/usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse.ini` file, but now getting the error message:

```
Incompatible JavaHL library loaded.  1.7.x or later required.
```

and can't seem to find out how to upgrade my JavaHL.  I've reinstalled the subclipse plugin, which apparently also installs JavaHL version 1.7.1, so perhaps this isn't a case of JavaHL not being installed, but perhaps unfindable? - Anyone with any ideas?

** EDIT **

As mentioned below the links provided in the accepted answer have stopped working, but you can [download updated files here](https://launchpad.net/~dominik-stadler/+archive/subversion-1.7/+sourcepub/2118558/+listing-archive-extra) (credit to Rekhyt) but you will need subclipse version 1.8.x which you can install by adding http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x to Eclipse

I installed subclipse 1.8 first then installed these files in order:

1. [libsvn-java_1.7.2-0ubuntu0~ppa1_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/~dominik-stadler/+archive/subversion-1.7/+files/libsvn1_1.7.2-0ubuntu0~ppa1_amd64.deb)
2. [subversion_1.7.2-0ubuntu0~ppa1_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/~dominik-stadler/+archive/subversion-1.7/+files/subversion_1.7.2-0ubuntu0~ppa1_amd64.deb)
3. [libsvn1_1.7.2-0ubuntu0~ppa1_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/~dominik-stadler/+archive/subversion-1.7/+files/libsvn-java_1.7.2-0ubuntu0~ppa1_amd64.deb)

If you need 32 bit [go to the launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/~dominik-stadler/+archive/subversion-1.7/+sourcepub/2118558/+listing-archive-extra) and click the 'subversion - 1.7.2-0ubuntu0~ppa1' link at the bottom of the page - this will bring up all the relevant files

Comment: [This source](http://steveliles.github.com/subversion_1_7_eclipse_integration_in_ubuntu_12.html) points out that the path to be entered in the eclipse.ini changed for Ubuntu 12.10. It's now `-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni/`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because of **[that](http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL#head-5ccce53a67ca6c3965de863ae91e2642eab537de)**

First of all I had to uninstall the old packages before installing the new ones (thanks to [Sergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/436035/sergi))

**for i386**

1. go to [here](https://launchpad.net/~dominik-stadler/+archive/ppa/+build/2901257)
2. install in order geb packages
3. [libsvn1_1.7.1-0ubuntu0~ppa4_i386.deb (979.2 KiB)](https://launchpad.net/~dominik-stadler/+archive/ppa/+build/2901257/+files/libsvn1_1.7.1-0ubuntu0~ppa10_i386.deb)
4. [subversion_1.7.1-0ubuntu0~ppa4_i386.deb (1.2 MiB)](https://launchpad.net/~dominik-stadler/+archive/ppa/+build/2901257/+files/subversion_1.7.1-0ubuntu0~ppa10_i386.deb)
5. [libsvn-java_1.7.1-0ubuntu0~ppa4_i386.deb](https://launchpad.net/~dominik-stadler/+archive/ppa/+build/2901257/+files/libsvn-java_1.7.1-0ubuntu0~ppa10_i386.deb)

**for amd64**

1. go to **[here](https://launchpad.net/~dominik-stadler/+archive/ppa/+build/2901256)**
2. install in order geb packages
3. [libsvn1_1.7.1-0ubuntu0~ppa4_amd64.deb (1.0 MiB)](https://launchpad.net/~dominik-stadler/+archive/ppa/+build/2901256/+files/libsvn1_1.7.1-0ubuntu0~ppa10_amd64.deb)
4. [subversion_1.7.1-0ubuntu0~ppa4_amd64.deb (1.2 MiB)](https://launchpad.net/~dominik-stadler/+archive/ppa/+build/2901256/+files/subversion_1.7.1-0ubuntu0~ppa10_amd64.deb)
5. [libsvn-java_1.7.1-0ubuntu0~ppa4_amd64.deb (446.7 KiB)](https://launchpad.net/~dominik-stadler/+archive/ppa/+build/2901256/+files/libsvn-java_1.7.1-0ubuntu0~ppa10_amd64.deb)

it worked for me.

Comment: Apologies - should have stated that this is for a 64 bit machine, can you change your answer to reflect, if possible?  Also, can you explain a bit more, I'm not quite sure I understand your points - am I suppose to install everything from that page, or just the deb packages listed 3-5 in your answer?

Comment: It worked for me too. Just note that I had to uninstall the old packages before installing the new ones.

Comment: Thank you :)  Like you said I used `apt-get` to remove the above packages then reinstalled them all and then reinstalled subclipse and after a reboot it's working fine.

Comment: I tried the method above for AMD64 (although the links are no longer valid - used: https://launchpad.net/~dominik-stadler/+archive/ppa/+build/2889157 ).  However, when installing libsvn I receveive the following:   Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libserf-private.  
I installed libserf-0-0-dev but can't find a way to get around this.  Any ideas?

Comment: Sadly those launchpad's items are not anymore available, someone can give me another place to get them, thanks.

Comment: @jean-christophe-meillaud version 1.7.2 is out which might be the reason for the links to be broken. as rekhyt mentioned in his answer, the mentioned packages can be found [here](https://launchpad.net/~dominik-stadler/+archive/subversion-1.7/+packages). ubuntu releases lucid to precise are supported.

Comment: Again looks like URL has changed for AMD64 - now https://launchpad.net/+search?field.text=64+build+of+subversion&field.actions.search=Search

Comment: Added [this](https://launchpad.net/~aroth/+archive/ppa) PPA to Synaptic, then installed the components in same order like described in the answer. Also had to create a symbolic link from /usr/lib/libsvnjavahl-1.so to /usr/lib/jni/libsvnjavahl-1.so.

Comment: All you need is `sudo  apt-get install libsvn-java` and update `java.library.path` to `/usr/lib/jni`. Follow instructions in http://islandlinux.org/howto/installing-javahl-subclipseeclipse-ubuntu.

Answer (score 23):

Alternatively, you may do the following, which automates the package installation:

```
apt-add-repository ppa:dominik-stadler/subversion-1.7

apt-get update

apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: This is the best solution to the problem. Thanks Anon & Piotr.

Comment: I am on Mint 12 and this is what worked for me. I downloaded the packages mentioned in the accepted answer and kept getting errors saying they weren't deb packages.

Comment: All you need is `sudo  apt-get install libsvn-java` and update `java.library.path` to `/usr/lib/jni`. Follow instructions in http://islandlinux.org/howto/installing-javahl-subclipseeclipse-ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, I can't comment yet (or I don't understand how this site works :-)), but maybe [Dave Shuck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203663/dave-shuck) interested in it: if you change the dependencies of the .deb package, and remove the libserf-private everything works fine. Easiest to do that with this script:  [videbcontrol](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=636724)

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot comment yet and my edit has been rejected:

I stumbled across the same problem. The repositories of Xubuntu 10.11 are out of date. Packages can be found at [this](https://launchpad.net/~dominik-stadler/+archive/subversion-1.7/+packages) location. Proceed according to javaloper's posting.

Answer (score 0):

Download files `libserf`, `libaprutil`, `libsvn1`, `subversion`, `libsvn-java` from [here](http://packages.debian.org/sid/subversion).

During download choose appropriate environment i.e `32bit` or `64bit` version.

Comment: Care to edit your answer and clearly state that is just to help fix broken links